# при нажатии на кнопку отправить ее id в другую активность используя intent

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Имеются две активности, в одной из них 4 кнопки, все они ведут во вторую активность, нужно при нажатии на кнопку с помощью intent передать id этой кнопки в другую активность. Искал на англоязычных форумах, но так и не понял как это лучше сделать.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Если вы по [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/290569/robert-mulyukov) то вам нужен не ID кнопки, а ID записи в таблице (это автоинкрементируемый уникальный идентификатор, назначаемый базой каждой новой записи). Если вы сделали ID записей в базе по ID кнопки, то это плохая идея. Так как ID кнопки может измениться при пересборке приложения от добавления других ресурсов и всю вашу таблицу придется переписывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробую угадать вашу разметку
допустим:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Кнопка 1"
/>
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Кнопка 2"
/>
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Кнопка 3"
/>
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Кнопка 4"
/>
```

При объявлении класса активности можно назначить активность обработчиком события `onClick`

```
public class Activityname extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // найдем View-элементы
        button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        // присваиваем обработчик кнопкам
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId()){//получаем id нажатой кнопки
            case R.id.button1:
                //go to activity 1
                break;   
            case R.id.button2: //и так далее...  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, прямо то, что надо

Answer (score 1):

Для начала тебе нужно получить id - кнопки.

Например: `int idButton = myButton.getId();`

Далее тебе нужно создать интент,положить в него значение и запустить новую активность.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this , newActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyIdButton", idButton);
startActivity(intent);
```

И  в новой активности тебе нужно получить эти данные

```
String yourIdButton = getIntent().getIntExtra("keyIdButton");
```